# SAS: Want to know how to pass data from a WORK.WHATEVER table into a Netezza table

Tags: sql, sas, etl, netezza

Using SAS V 9.xxx.

How do I pass data from a table in the generic WORK library to a table in Netezza.

Right now I can take data out of Netezza and store in the WORK library, for example:

```
/* using “connect to” */

proc sql;
connect to netezza (&us_mkt.);  
execute (

drop table &tempdir..SALES_TBL_TST1; 

create table &tempdir..SALES_TBL_TST1
as
   select * from &tempdir..SALES_TBL;
   /*select * from &tempdir..SALES_TBL */

) by netezza;
    disconnect from netezza;
quit;

/* using “connect using” */

proc sql;

   connect using ROLAP;

   drop table WORK.SALES_TBL_TST2;

     create table WORK.SALES_TBL_TST2 AS
   select * from connection to ROLAP
      (select * from USER_ROLAP.SALES_TBL);

   insert into WORK.SALES_TBL_TST2
   select * from connection to ROLAP
      (select * from &tempdir..SALES_TBL);

quit;
```

But what if I want to put data back into Netezza from the WORK library. So for example:

```
  insert into &tempdir..SALES_TBL_TST1   
select * from WORK.SALES_TBL_TST2;
```

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can do move data by using libname statment.
Need to  bulkload(loads data in bulk and faster) for fast transfer of records. Once libnames are defined . data can be moved from work to Netezza either by proc sql, datastep or proc append. Moving data code is similar to data movement between two SAS libaries(syntax wise).

Below is the code copied from http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003181092.htm

```
 libname sasflt 'SAS-data-library';


 libname net_air netezza user=louis pwd=fromage
    server=air2 database=flights;
```

Example by Proc sql

```
 proc sql;
create table net_air.flights98
   (bulkload=YES bl_options='logdir "c:\temp\netlogs"') 
    as select * from sasflt.flt98;
quit;
```

Comment: Could also say "insert into net_air.flights98 (bulkload=YES bl_options='logdir "c:\temp\netlogs"') select * from sasflt.flt98;" ?

Comment: If I don't add the  (bulkload=YES bl_options='logdir "c:\temp\netlogs"') phrase will it go slower or will it error out?

Comment: slower. under 5 millions u may not even need it. bulkload=YES is importsnt as number of records increase

Comment: Wait is it net_air or %net_air. ? Don't you have to surround that lib name in SAS?

Comment: net_air. no need to sorround for netezza as you sre not mentioining a path here